# How can I use pandas.query() to check if a string exists in a list within the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
    col1
0   ['str1', 'str2']
1   ['str3', 'str4']
2   []
3   ['str2', 'str4']
4   ['str1', 'str3']
5   []
```

I'm trying to craft a df.query() string that would be the equivalent of saying "'str3' in col1".
So it would return:

```
    col1
1   ['str3', 'str4']
4   ['str1', 'str3']
```

I've tried df.query("col1.str.contains('str3')") but that results in

"None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=652)] are in the [index]"

I'm guessing because many of the lists in this column may be empty and convert to nan floats instead of strings?

It's highly preferable that I use query strings for this since rather than list constructors, since I want this to be a script where other users can filter a dataframe using these query strings that they may craft.

Comment: Are the items in "col1" lists or strings representations of lists?

Comment: is it possible to explode the lists-in-columns into new columns?

Comment: @mozway They are lists containing strings.

Comment: @ti7 It's something I can do, but I don't really see that usefulness of that approach. The column may have a list containing 0 to x elements, so there may be many columns added, most of which will contain empty elements, and the order in which the strings appear is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Series of lists, you can't use `query`, instead go for boolean indexing with a list comprehension.

```
df[["str3" in x for x in df['col1']]]
```

If you need to chain the command, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a lambda:

```
df.loc[lambda d: ["str3" in x for x in d['col1']]]
```

Output:

```
           col1
1  [str3, str4]
4  [str1, str3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be some way to do it with queries, since I was intending for users of the script to be able to pass the query as an argument, but it looks like this may not be possible.

Comment: Your other comment actually led to a kind of solution that while not golden gives me the result I want while still allowing other users to just use a query string. It boils down to just converting the series of lists in the dataframe into string representations of lists, and then using the typical: col1.str.contains('str3')

Comment: @Peregrin5 that's not without pitfalls but yes, it's possible. Maybe a cleaner approach would be to join with a separator (that won't be in the strings). For example `df.assign(x=df['col1'].apply('|'.join)).query('x.str.contains("str3")')`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible in your set up to use lambda functions? Because it seems that data could be filtered with mask:

`df['col'].apply(labmda x: 'str3' in x)`

Comment: It's possible. I know there are ways to do this without queries, but I was hoping for a method that used a query string so users of the script could pass the query in as an argument. In this case, they (or I) would directly need to edit the code of the script which isn't ideal.